# How can we compare Fourier Transform and Stieltjes transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

This is has come up while reading the link :
https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/245a-notes-5-free-probability/#comment-481225
where it is mentioned that : "Another important (and closely related) analogy is that while the distribution of sums of independent commutative random variables can be quickly computed via the characteristic function (i.e. the Fourier transform of the distribution), the distribution of sums of freely independent non-commutative random variables can be quickly computed using the Stieltjes transform instead (or with closely related objects, such as the $R$-transform of Voiculescu)"

Now, I am trying to understand the Stieltjes transformation. I understand that Fourier transform is defined on a function but where the Stieltjes transformation is defined? Is ti defined on a distribution function? Is there any other analogy between Fourier Transform and Stieltjes transformation?